# How to take property value from a datalist in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

my HTML:

```
 <input list="tasks" id="selected-task" [(ngModel)]=query (keyup)=filter() name="tasks" class="select-project">
 <datalist id="tasks" #tasksDataList >            
    <option *ngFor="let item of taskList"  (click)="select(item)" >{{item.title}}</option>

 </datalist>
```

in my component:

```
select(item) {
this.query = item;   
this.taskList = [];
}
```

In the datalist I am showing all item.titles, when I choose one, I need to save item.id in a variable, but I can't access the id value from the selected item.
I have tried with:

```
select(item:myClass) {
this.query = item.title;  
this.id = item.id;
this.taskList = [];
}
```

but it's shows then id is undefined.

So any suggestions when the user selects an item from the datalist how to save the id of the selected item in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

After many tries I just ended with the conclusion that angular and datalist (HTML5) are not working well together. If you want just string to be chosen, it is okay, but if u want to work with objects like in my case you can't achieve the desired result. Alternative way is to use select and after that using ul with list items, which are taking the data from the hidden select. So basically there is a little more work for the front-ender but it's the only way :)